# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 "Integrals", Problem *40: Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt=a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

The following is the last problem in Chapter 13, "Integrals", from Spivak's Calculus.

> *40. Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[0,x]$ for all $x>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=a$. Prove that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt=a$$
>
> Hint: The condition $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=a$ implies that
> $f(t)$ is close to $a$ for $t\geq$ some $N$. This means that
> $\int_N^{N+M} f(t)dt$ is close to $Ma$. If $M$ is large in comparison
> to $N$, then $\frac{Ma}{N+M}$ is close to $a$.

As frequently happens, the solution manual solution is terse and skips many steps. I attempted to fill in the intermediate steps in that proof, and I present both the original proof and my version of that proof below.

**Here is the solution manual solution**

> **Proof**
>
> If $\epsilon>0$, pick $N\geq 0$ so that $|f(t)-a<\epsilon$ for $t \geq
>  N$. Then for $N \geq 0$ we have
>
> $$\left | \int_N^{N+M} f(t)dt-Ma \right |<\epsilon M\tag{1}$$
>
> so
>
> $$\left | \frac{N}{N+M} \int_N^{N+M} f(t)dt - \frac{Ma}{N+M} \right
>  |<\frac{\epsilon M}{N+M}<\epsilon\tag{2}$$
>
> Choose $M$ so that
>
> $$\left | \frac{Ma}{N+M}-a \right |<\epsilon\tag{3}$$
>
> and
>
> $$\left | \frac{1}{N+M} \int_0^N f(t)dt \right |<\epsilon\tag{4}$$
>
> Then
>
> $$\left | \frac{1}{N+M} \int_0^{N+M} f(t)dt-a\right |<3\epsilon\tag{5}$$
>
> $\blacksquare$

Note that it seems there is a typo in $(2)$, on that $\frac{N}{N+M}$ factor in the first term.

I'd like to try to go through the proof with more intermediate steps and explanations. My question is if this longer proof has all the details correct.

**Here is my proof**

> $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=a$ means
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N\ \forall x, x>N\implies
> > |f(x)-a|<\epsilon$$
>
> $$\implies a-\epsilon<f(x)<a+\epsilon$$
>
> Let $P$ be a partition of $[N,N+M]$.
>
> Then $$L(f,P)=\sum m_i \Delta t_i<\sum (a+\epsilon)\Delta t_i =
> > (a+\epsilon)M$$
>
> and
>
> $$U(f,P)=\sum M_i \Delta t_i > \sum (a-\epsilon)\Delta t_i =
> > (a-\epsilon)M$$
>
> Therefore, since $L(f,P)\leq \int_N^{N+M} f\leq U(f,P)$, it must be
> that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have
>
> $$M(a-\epsilon)\leq \int\limits_N^{N+M} f \leq M(a+\epsilon)\tag{6}$$
>
> $$\left | \int\limits_N^{N+M} f-Ma \right |<\epsilon M\tag{1}$$
>
> Divide everything by $\frac{1}{N+M}$
>
> $$\left | \frac{\int\limits_N^{N+M} f}{N+M} - \frac{Ma}{N+M} \right
>  |<\frac{M\epsilon}{N+M}$$
>
> $$\frac{Ma}{N+M}-\frac{M\epsilon}{N+M}<\frac{\int\limits_N^{N+M}f}{N+M}<\frac{Ma}{N+M}+\frac{M\epsilon}{N+M}\tag{7}$$
>
> Up to this point, everything has been a consequence of our initial
> assumption that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$, and some fixed
> closed interval $[N,M]$.
>
> Let's now change $M$. In particular, let's choose $M$ such that
> $\frac{Ma}{N+M}$ is very close to $a$, ie
>
> $$\left | \frac{Ma}{N+M}-a \right |<\epsilon$$
>
> Note that $\frac{M\epsilon}{N+M}<\epsilon$ for all $M$.
>
> Then, from $(7)$ we have
>
> $$a-\epsilon-\epsilon<\frac{\int\limits_N^{N+M}f}{N+M}<a+\epsilon+\epsilon$$
>
> $$-2\epsilon<\frac{\int\limits_N^{N+M}f}{N+M}<2\epsilon$$
>
> At this point we can go back to the original limit we are interested
> in
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt=a$$
>
> $$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left [ \frac{1}{x} \int_0^Nf(t)dt
>  +\frac{1}{x}\int_N^x f(t)dt \right ]$$
>
> $$=\lim\limits_{M \to \infty} \left [ \frac{1}{N+M} \int_0^Nf(t)dt
>  +\frac{1}{N+M}\int_N^{N+M} f(t)dt \right ]$$
>
> $$=0+a$$
>
> $$=a$$
>
> $\blacksquare$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Try to avoid using partitions with $| \int f | \leq \int |f|$. Also, you have  typo. You need to write -a in the last line before your limit calculation.

Comment: I still don't love this proof. If you're going to break out the definition of a limit, then, aesthetically speaking, you should conclude with the definition of a limit. Add $\frac{1}{N + M} \int_0^n f$ back in, show that $|\frac{1}{N + M} \int_0^{N + M} f - a | < 3\epsilon$, and then conclude from the definition of the limit that the limit is as claimed.

Comment: This is a standard analysis trick by the way, so remember it well. Break it up into two pieces: one that gets as small as you want, and one that's as close as you want.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Are your criticisms valid for both proofs above or just for the second one? The first one didn't explicitly use the definition of limit. The only thing I believe the second proof does is make the implicit steps explicit.

Comment: Spivak's proof is a limit definition proof. It's just missing the line "by the definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty}$, ..." My criticisms were intended for your proof. I would try to argue with the integral triangle inequality, and then conclude with the definition of a limit, as Spivak has done somewhat briefly.